# why the method column_types is undefined in Rails 5.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

Im doing an assignment for a class and it uses column_types method in a rspec test.

```
  it "User database structure in place" do
        expect(User.column_names).to include "password_digest", "username"
        expect(User.column_types["username"].type).to eq :string
        expect(User.column_types["password_digest"].type).to eq :string
        expect(User.column_types["created_at"].type).to eq :datetime
        expect(User.column_types["updated_at"].type).to eq :datetime
```

end

Error: when i run rpsec in the command line.
Rails 5.0
Ubuntu 14.10

Failure/Error: expect(User.column_types["username"].type).to eq :string

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `column_types' for #<Class:0x000000053a0188>
   Did you mean?  columns
                  column_names
 # ./spec/assignment_spec.rb:67:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/assignment_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit  `class User < ApplicationRecord
end`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method was removed in [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/70ac072976c8cc6f013f0df3777e54ccae3f4f8c#diff-6c8fd220c92c2b25aa29891b59d00c04L223). It's not so easy to find it.

But, the reason is was not documented, it's because the method itself is not documented (Maybe it's just for internal use).

See [this comment](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.7/activerecord/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb#L237) `:nodoc:` on the method when it existed:

```
def column_types # :nodoc:
    @column_types ||= columns_hash.transform_values(&:cast_type).tap do |h|
      h.default = Type::Value.new
    end
  end
```

You can read through the [commit's](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/70ac072976c8cc6f013f0df3777e54ccae3f4f8c#diff-6c8fd220c92c2b25aa29891b59d00c04L223) description to understand the why and maybe see if there's something else you can do.

**EDIT**

Take a look at [these lines](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/70ac072976c8cc6f013f0df3777e54ccae3f4f8c#diff-6c8fd220c92c2b25aa29891b59d00c04R223) maybe `attributes_types` or `columns_hash` can solve your problem.

Comment: Using `attributes_types` worked great for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The method `column_types` is removed in Rails 5.

To get the type of column you can try following code:

```
User.column_for_attribute('username').type
```

This will return the type, here in your case: `:string`

Answer (score 1):

looks like in rails 5, `column_types` method no longer exist

Comment: How does one figure that out? I googled and did not say anything about it. Is there a website to check methods and deprecation ?

Comment: yeah, no body mentioned it http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#active-record-removals here.. -_-

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get a hash of all the column_types

```
User.columns_hash.each_with_object({}) { |obj, h| h[obj[1].name] = obj[1].sql_type }
```